# How to display saved enum value in DropDownListFor

Tags: enums, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I have a model named HtmlBlock that has an enum and a property with a type of that enum.

```
namespace MyDandyWebsite.Models
{
   public enum HtmlBlockType
 {
    Full_Width,
    OneThird_TwoThirds,
    TwoThirds_OneThird,
    OneThird_OneThird_OneThird,
    OneHalf_OneHalf,
    OneQuarter_ThreeQuarter,
    ThreeQuarter_OneQuarter,
    OneQuarter_OneHalf_OneQuarter,
    OneQuarter_OneQuarter_OneQuarter_OneQuarter
}

public class HtmlBlock
{
  ...
    [Required]
    public HtmlBlockType BlockType { get; set; }
  ...
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }
  ...
    //Initialze class
    public HtmlBlock()
    {
        DropDownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        DropDownItems.Add((new SelectListItem { Text = "Full-Width", Value = "0" }));

        ... add the rest of the enums that are too long and wrap badly

    }


}


            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    model => model.BlockType,
                    new SelectList(Model.DropDownItems, 
                    "Value", "Text", Model.BlockType)
                )
```

The selected blocktype is correctly saved to the database and gets used and listed correctly every where except in the above dropdown list, where the first item in the enum list is displayed.
If I change the datatype of class HtmlBlock.BlockType to an int, then the Dropdown list displays correctly, but every simple displayfor then shows an int rather that say, "TwoThirds_OneThird" which is what I want.

I see a lot of workarounds in google, I am asking if anyone knows how to make the existing code display the saved value in the DropdownFor. According to what I have read, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes

Install MVC 5.1 and use @Html.EnumDropDownListFor